# First image in <body> greater than 200 px Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For social media sharing I am trying to get the first image URL which is greater than 200px using jQuery. This is my code which is not working:

```
$("body img").each(function() {
  var $minHeight = 200;
  if ($(this).height() > $minHeight) {
    $(this).attr('src')
  }
});
```

After getting the right image I need to change the default image URL in `content="default-image.png"` below:

```
<meta property="og:image" name="twitter:image" content="default-image.png"/>
```

This is a working selector for meta tag I found:

```
$('meta[property=og\\:image]').attr('content','new-image.png');
```

I Found My Code Is Working But...

```
$("body img").each(function() {
  var $minHeight = 200;
  if ($(this).height() < $minHeight) {
  $x = $(this).attr('src')
  }
});

$('meta[property=og\\:image]').attr('content',$x);

$(".share a[href*='pinterest']").prop("href","https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://mywebsite.com/mypage&media="+$x);
```

But above script is not working with greater than sign as needed `if ($(this).height() > $minHeight)`

Comment: Syntax error: `').('`

Comment: @Vohuman what should i use?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. What is the role of `('meta[property=og\\:image]')`? Note that you should listen to the `load` even before  getting the height of the element.

Comment: @blackfire how background image is defined in css?

Comment: @Vohuman i edited the question

Comment: That actually doesn't help. Please provide more context and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Vohuman Is my question is clear now?

Answer (score 0):

So, when you do $("body img") jquery returns an array of elements.

If I am understanding it correct, you need the image which is of ACTUAL HEIGHT but not the CSS provided height. In this case:

```
var ImagesGreaterThan200Height =jQuery.grep($("body img"), function( img, i ) {
    if(img.naturalHeight > 200)
         return img;
});
```

From the above code, you will get an array of Images which are greater than 200px in height and for the first image you just need to do:

```
ImagesGreaterThan200Height[0] // This returns the first Image
```

Hope this helps!